# Why My Image Source In Xaml Doesnt show?

Tags: xamarin

I Have An Image that i drag and drop to my android resources folder, I just copied it and paste it in the UWP Folder. They have the same name, but if I run the UWP Project (That is the only project that I can run, because I dont have a Mac, and my Android emulator is all black screen, I have remembered that I think I cant run it because I dont have an Intel proccessor or something like that).

It only dislplays a big white square, and I checked if the image property Build Action is on Resource, It is on AndroidResource, I don't find a "normal resource"

Answer (score 0):

In my UWP I set Build Action to Content

Example of code:

```
<Image Grid.Row="0" x:Name="ClickableLogo" Grid.Column="1"  
Source="edroplogo_420.png"  
HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
```